# How to get the used amount of memory of heap in EHcache?

Tags: java

Actually i want to know the occupied  memory by cache. It will give me the element count in the size not the used space. So how to get it??

Comment: Please try the below link:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841441/how-can-i-get-ehcache-to-keep-heap-size-bytes-statistics-for-unbounded-caches

Comment: Thanks for your comments but i was looking for simple solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getStatistics()` method of `net.sf.ehcache.Cache` will give the information of used memory in bytes.

```
StatisticsGateway stats = cache.getStatistics();
stats.getLocalHeapSizeInBytes();
```